# Sketching the region defined by a system

Tags: graphing-functions

I have the following system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
u     \\
v      
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
xe^y     \\
ye^x     
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

which is enclosed in an area given by $$ u = 1, u = e, v = 1, v = e$$

To be honest I am not even sure where to start, I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first coordinate: we have $1\leq x e^x\leq e$.
Take logarithms to get $0\leq\ln(x)+y\leq1$ which means that $y\geq-\ln(x)$ and $y\leq1-\ln(x)$.    Similarly you'll get a sketch for the second coordinate; here we have $0\leq\ln(y)+x$ and $\ln(y)+x\leq1$, that is, $y\geq e^{-x}$ and $y\leq e^{1-x}$.

Now feel free to draw.